# Trying to find occurrence of a number followed by a comma using a regex

Tags: java, regex, kotlin

This is the string I am trying to validate with regex: `var mString = "14 90,"`.
I want to check if the string contains a occurrence of a set of numbers followed by a comma, in this case `90,`

I have this regex pattern:

```
var pattern: Pattern = Pattern.compile(".*/([0-9]+,)+/g.*")
```

But when evaluating the string it returns false:

```
if(pattern.matcher(mString).find()){
        //found it!
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Note that `.matches(".*([0-9]+,).*")` is very inefficient since the first `.*` causes a lot of backtracking. Compare [4237 steps](https://regex101.com/r/S8EphM/1) with Mike's solution and [8 steps](https://regex101.com/r/S8EphM/2) with mine. You will avoid many performance issues if you write your patterns efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java patterns do not apply modifiers nor contexts within the regular expression string itself. With `".*/([0-9]+,)+/g.*"`, it looks like you're trying to apply the expression globally with the `g` mode. If you want to apply modifiers then you should actually add them as the second argument to `Pattern.compile`:

```
Pattern.compile(".*([0-9]+,).*", Pattern.DOTALL)
```

In your case, you probably don't need mode modifiers. Just use `.*([0-9]+,).*` as your regular expression:

```
if (mString.matches(".*([0-9]+,).*")) {
    // Found it!
}
```

> ### Update:
>
> I had initially believed that inline modifiers were unavailable in Java, but it turns out that `java.util.Pattern` actually does support inline modifiers. This is documented in the first Javadoc-style comment within the `Pattern` class:
>
> ```
>    /**
>     * Regular expression modifier values.  Instead of being passed as
>     * arguments, they can also be passed as inline modifiers.
>     * For example, the following statements have the same effect.
>     * <pre>
>     * RegExp r1 = RegExp.compile("abc", Pattern.I|Pattern.M);
>     * RegExp r2 = RegExp.compile("(?im)abc", 0);
>     * </pre>
>     *
>     * The flags are duplicated so that the familiar Perl match flag
>     * names are available.
>     */
> ```
>
> Further details for what character to use for each modifier can be found on each modifier constant in the same class. For example, `Pattern.DOTALL` can be enabled with the expression `(?s)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `".*/([0-9]+,)+/g.*"` is a "ruined", corrupt pattern since you included `.*/` and `/g.*` by mistake. The point is to look for `[0-9]+,` (or even `[0-9],`) anywhere inside a string.

You may use a pattern like `[0-9],` and use the **Kotlin [`contains()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/contains.html) method** or Java's `Matcher#find()` by passing the regex to the method:

```
var mString = "14 90,"
var pattern = "[0-9]+,".toRegex()
if(mString.contains(pattern)){
    println("Valid")
}
```

See [Kotlin demo](http://rextester.com/WEW58612).

Here, the `pattern` is instantiated as an instance of the `Regex` class and the regex object is passed to the `contains` method.

**Java code**:

```
if (Pattern.compile("[0-9],").matcher(s).find()) {
    System.out.println("Matched");
}
```